# How do we compile a multiple output keras model

Tags: python-2.7, keras, keras-layer

As the title says how do we compile a keras functional model with mulitple outputs?

```
# Multiple Outputs
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

# input layer
visible = Input(shape=(4,2))
# feature extraction
extract = LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(visible)
# classification output
class11 = LSTM(10)(extract)
class12 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(class11)
class13 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(class12)

output1 = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(class13)

# sequence output
output2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))(extract)
# output

model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=[output1, output2])

# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

There are two output branches with two different types of output values. First output is a dense layer with softmax activation function and other output is a time distributed layer with tanh activation.

How should we compile this model. I tried this way

```
model.compile(optimizer=['rmsprop','adam'],
              loss=['categorical_crossentropy','mse'],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But its giving this error

> ValueError: ('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', ['rmsprop', 'adam'])

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I already gave one and also accepted your answer

Comment: Thanks a lot then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you want to set two separate optimizer what is not plausible in `keras`. You need to choose either `rmsprop` or `adam` as the main optimizer.